# Android .apk loading in the memory

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to know, when we click on a application in android, how does it loaded in the memory, and how process is created for that application, and where can i see the code flow for this in android source(dialer application).

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to traditional execution  a pre-running process called zygote already containing the dalvik vm and many other system libraries is told to fork a child which becomes your application process  This then loads your dex classes out of your apk.  The zygote and dalvik aosp sources may be of interest.

Note that a launch may not mean a new process as it may be possible to launch the activity in an existing process belonging to the application userid.  Conversely, what seems to the user like de-minimizing a backgrounded activity can actually involve creation of a new process to pick up where a disposed predecessor was paused.